# Java EE 6, 5, 7 | List of managed beans or classes: EJBs , JSF beans and ..?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, managed-bean

could someone one the current list of *managed Beans* or classes in Java EE 5,6,7?
apart from EJBs and JSF managed beans, are they other classes ?

In the book " EJB 3 in Action", at chapter 5 (*learning advanced EJB concepts*) it got mentioned that:

> "DI is supported only in the managed classes and that you cannot use
>   injection in helper or utility classes."

That's  why I wanted to know what are the managed beans that can in general support Dependency injection.

-please don't forget to mention online references and doc, if any -
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Docs for Platform MBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html#mxbeans)?

Comment: @Brad I looked into it just now... good Stuff. do you have some more ? thanks!

Comment: @Brad: um, I don't think the concept of "managed beans" arthur is talking about has anything to do with MBeans. He seeems to be talking about classes whose instances are managed by a container, have dependency injection performed, etc.

Comment: why are you downvoted my question? I just asked some simple question. the question is not dumb, nor confusing it is direct... I wish I could trace the one who downvoted it!!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is not like the topic is unkwown to me. as I mentioned out of my little experience some cases like EJB, JSF Mbean. I was thinking there are more to that than just these, that's why I asked,and thought it would be beneficiary for other youngster like me. As you see the topic is wider as it was supposed.

Comment: @arthur now it looks more like a question, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry i forgot the context.. wanted to get quick to the point . ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of EE 6:

- EJB (EJB 3.1, section 2.8 - "Relationship to to Managed Bean Specification")
- CDI (JSR-299, section 1.2.3 - "Relationship to managed beans")
- JSF (Managed Beans 1.0, section MB.1.2)

Since specifications are expected to build on top of the managed beans specification, the platform specification does not provide a comprehensive list, so you would have to review each specification included in EE 6.  My evidence for JSF is the weakest, since the latest JSF specification does not explicitly state that it builds on top of the managed beans specification.  However, the managed beans specification itself states that it is intended as a generalization of JSF.

That said, table EE.5-1 in the EE 6 platform specification contains the list of component classes supporting injection, PostConstruct, and PreDestroy.  This list is arguably more useful than knowing which a list of component technologies that are explicitly "managed beans".

- Servlet (servlets, servlet filters, event listeners)
- JSP (tag handlers, tag library event listeners)
- JSF (scoped managed beans)
- JAX-WS (service endpoints, handlers)
- EJB (beans, interceptors)
- Managed Beans [from the managed beans specification]
- CDI (CDI-style managed beans [almost any class in an archive with beans.xml], decorators)
- Java EE platform (main class (static) [application client], login callback handler)

Comment: Does a CDI-injected object in dependent scope count as managed?

Comment: @TomAnderson per the CDI spec, "As defined by this specification, most Java classes, including all JavaBeans, are managed beans", so I think so, but I'm not a CDI expert.

Comment: The phrase "most Java classes" is not something you want to find in a specification! I'm also not a CDI expert. You can definitely inject such beans, but i don't think you can, say, apply an interceptor to method calls to them. I have no idea if that means they're managed or not. It doesn't matter much; CDI beans in general are definitely on the list.

Comment: The "most Java classes" statement is colloquial.  The precise rules for when a class is a managed bean are clearly stated in section 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that any Java Class can be a managed bean by writing it to conform to the [MBean Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html).

Your questions asks for a *"current list of managed beans"* in Java EE. So the short answer is that *"it depends on whether the applications you are running are registering MBeans or not"*. You can run a JMX client (e.g. [MX4J](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/)) against your JVM to find out what beans are registered.

The link I gave you for the [Platform MBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html#mxbeans) describes some that may be available by default in your JVM.

Comment: I think you got a point, I was looking for Mbeans in the sense of being managed by Container or an/or Application Server and from  one  API  of java EE edition(like JSF 2.0, or Servlets , and EJBs) .. but I think you got generically right. I got to see the MBean spec.

Comment: I will wait if someone answers my directly my question, if not I'll accept yours. but first +1