# EJB injection into non managed objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

we are upgrading our web application to Oracle WebLogic 12c with EJB 3.x, and we got an issue.

This is the scenario...

We have a simple EJBs that we are going to call MyService, defined with its bean and local/remote interfaces defined by the EJB 3.x annotations.

Here is a pseudo code of the scenario:

```
class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @EJB private MyService myService;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // Here myService is correctly instantiated, so we do something...
    }

}
```

Now we have to move the contextInitialized method logic inside an utility class, so the new scenario will be:

```
class MyUtility {

  @EJB private MyService myService;

  public void doSomething() {
      // Here myService is NULL!!!!!
  }

}

class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        new MyUtility().doSomething();
    }

}
```

I have read a lot of documentation about that problem, and I discovered that only some kind of classes are scanned by the Application Server to resolve the injected EJBs ( [Java EE 6, 5, 7 | List of managed beans or classes: EJBs , JSF beans and ..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122127/java-ee-6-5-7-list-of-managed-beans-or-classes-ejbs-jsf-beans-and) ).

Is there a workaround to force the scanning of a custom class like mine with WebLogic?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Can't you just pass the EJB to the constructor of `MyUtility`?

Comment: No, the utility class must hide its internal processing logic.

Comment: Last resort would be a traditional lookup via `InitialContext`

Comment: +1 for @fvu - good old-school InitialContext lookup is something you can always do, with caution that MyUtility class initialization depends on EJB that should be already active and registered with JNDI. Did not work with WebLogic but on WebSphere you can define run order for your WAR and EJB JAR modules, so you should make sure your EJB is initialized before MyUtility.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to wrap you Injection into a CDI-Component and to use this one in your code. CDI has the capability to work in standalone java, as soon as you configured it well.
Another helpful option can be the fact, that CDI supports EJB-injection too (in some usecases):
`CDI.current().select(MyService.class).get();`

BUT: EJBs has their own Transaction-Management. So I would prefer the wrapping into a cdi-component to get more controll in it.